# What's the proper way to model this real-world activity that seems to need circular references in OOP?

Tags: java, object-oriented, game-development, circular-dependency

I've been wrestling with a problem in a Java project about circular references.  I'm trying to model a real-world situation in which it seems the objects in question are interdependent and need to know about each other.

The project is a generic model of playing a board game.  The basic classes are non-specific, but are extended to deal with specifics of chess, backgammon and other games.  I coded this up as an applet 11 years ago with half a dozen different games, but the problem is that it's full of circular references.  I implemented it back then by stuffing all the intertwined classes in a single source file, but I get the idea that that's bad form in Java.  Now I want to implement a similar thing as an Android app, and I want to do things properly.

The classes are:

- RuleBook: an object that can be interrogated for such things as the
  initial layout of the Board, other initial game State information
  like who moves first, the Moves that are available, what happens to
  the game State after a proposed Move, and an evaluation of a current
  or proposed board position.
- Board: a simple representation of a game board, which can be
  instructed to reflect a Move.
- MoveList: a list of Moves.  This is dual-purpose: a choice of moves
  available at a given point, or a list of moves that have been made in
  the game.  It could be split into two near-identical classes, but
  that's not relevant to the question I'm asking and may complicate it
  further.
- Move: a single move.  It includes everything about the move as a list
  of atoms: pick up a piece from here, put it down there, remove a
  captured piece from there.
- State: the full state information of a game in progress.  Not only
  the Board position, but a MoveList, and other state information such
  as who is to move now.  In chess one would record whether the king
  and rooks of each player have been moved.

Circular references abound, for example: the RuleBook needs to know about the game State to determine what moves are available at a given time, but the game State needs to query the RuleBook for the initial starting layout and for what side effects accompany a move once it is made (e.g. who moves next).

I tried organising the new set of classes hierarchically, with RuleBook at the top as it needs to know about everything.  But this results in having to move lots of methods into the RuleBook class (such as making a move) making it monolithic and not particularly representative of what a RuleBook should be.

So what's the proper way to organise this?  Should I turn RuleBook into BigClassThatDoesAlmostEverythingInTheGame to avoid circular references, abandoning the attempt to model the real-world game accurately?  Or should I stick with the interdependent classes and coax the compiler into compiling them somehow, retaining my real-world model?  Or is there some obvious valid structure I'm missing?

Thanks for any help you can give!

Comment: What if the `RuleBook` took e.g. the `State` as an argument, and returned the valid `MoveList`, i.e. *"here's where we are now, what can be done next?"*

Comment: What @jonrsharpe said. When playing a real board game the rule book also doesn't know about any actual games being played. I would probably even introduce another class to actually calculate moves, but that might depend on how big this RuleBook class already is.

Comment: Avoiding the god object (BigClassThatDoesAlmostEverythingInTheGame) is much more important than avoiding circular references.

Comment: @user281377 they aren't necessarily mutually exclusive objectives, though!

Comment: Can you show the modeling attempts? A diagram for example?

Comment: Thanks for the comments on this. In answer to @jonrsharpe - that's how it works at the moment, so the RuleBook needs to know about the State.  But the State has all the game information as protected attributes, and it seems natural that one should tell the State to make the move.  For this, it needs to query the RuleBook (for who moves next, and to flag up things like the king has moved, etc.).  There comes the circular reference.

Comment: And in answer to @SebastiaanvandenBroek, I'm not sure how I'd code up a rulebook that works like a natural language one.  A notation to deal with things like "piece p moves in direction d and can/cannot jump over/land on other pieces" would be vastly more complicated than I could cope with right now.  So the RuleBook is interactive, and instead answers questions like "can piece p move to square s here" or "what are the valid moves at this point in game g?"

Comment: No need for a custom class `MoveList`, use `List<Move>`.

Comment: Also, the information from State which affects gameplay should be stored in Board, as it is part of the current position.

Comment: Contrary to the existing answers I think your design is poor and a proper fix should not result in circular references.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

> I've been wrestling with a problem in a Java project about circular references.

Java's garbage collector doesn't rely on reference counting techniques. Circular references do not cause any kind of problem in Java. Time spent eliminating perfectly natural circular references in Java is time wasted.

> I coded this up [...] but the problem is that it's full of circular references. I implemented it back then by **stuffing all the intertwined classes in a single source file**, [...]

Not necessary. If you just compile all the source files at once (e.g., `javac *.java`), the compiler will resolve all forward references without problems.

> Or should I stick with the interdependent classes and coax the compiler into compiling them somehow, [...]

Yes. Application classes are expected to be interdependent. Compiling all Java source files that belong to the same package at once isn't a clever hack, it's precisely the way Java is *supposed* to work.

Comment: "Circular references do not cause any kind of problem in Java." In terms of compilation, this is true. Circular references are [considered bad design](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/11856/whats-wrong-with-circular-references), though.

Comment: Circular references are perfectly natural in many situations, that's why Java and other modern languages use a sophisticated garbage collector instead of a simple reference counter.

Comment: Thanks for this!  Simply compiling everything at once with a wildcard didn't occur to me.

Comment: Java being able to resolve circular references is great, and it's definitely true that they're natural in many situations.  But OP presented a *specific* situation, and that ought to be considered.  Tangled spaghetti code is probably not the best way to handle this problem.

Comment: @Chop Yes, at a high level I agree you generally don't want your modules to depend on each other in a circular way if possible. But at the level of references, having an object graph with interconnected nodes is a very natural way to solve a huge space of common problems, and there's absolutely no reason not to do so in Java. It's not C++ where everything needs a clear ownership relationship.

Comment: @BrianGordon I agree circular references is often an easy way to solve a problem but with some experience you can always find a way to avoid them, which almost always happen to be a design pattern. If they save time at the beginning, circular reference can become a hassle when testing or maintaining (or even understandin). In my experience, KISS and SOLID are more enforced without them, and _those_ are the recommended way to program with Java.

Comment: Please don't spread unsubstantiated FUD about unrelated programming languages. Python has supported GC of reference cycles since ages ([docs](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/gcsupport.html), also on SO: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10962393) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428301/should-i-worry-about-circular-references-in-python)).

Comment: IMHO this answer is only mediocre, since there is not one word about circular references beeing useful for example of the OP.

Comment: @DocBrown That's because the extent to which *circular references* are part of the problem is not clear from the question. It appears that *forward references* were the bulk of the issue.

Comment: The change to cyclic references in Python 3.4 was a change to the semantics of Python's `finalize` equivalent; finalizers are now supported in reference cycles, at the expense of making finalized objects visible in more circumstances. The cyclic GC itself has been around for ages.

Answer (score 22):

Granted, circular dependencies are a questionable practice from a design point of view, but they are not prohibited, and from a purely technical point of view they are not even *necessarily problematic*, as you seem to regard them to be: they are perfectly legal in most scenarios, they are inevitable in some situations, and on some rare occasions they can even be regarded as a useful thing to have.

Actually, there are very few scenarios where the java compiler will deny a circular dependency.  (Note: there may be more, I can only think of the following right now.)

1. In inheritance: You cannot have a class A extend class B which in turn extends class A, and it is perfectly reasonable that you cannot have this, since the alternative would make absolutely no sense from a logical point of view.
2. Among method-local classes: classes declared within a method may not circularly reference each other.  This is probably nothing but a limitation of the java compiler, possibly because the ability to do such a thing is not useful enough to justify the additional complexity that would have to go into the compiler to support it.  (Most java programmers are not even aware of the fact that you can declare a class within a method, let alone declare multiple classes, and then having these classes circularly reference each other.)

So, it is important to realize and get it out of the way that the quest to minimize circular dependencies is a quest for design purity, not a quest for technical correctness.

As far as I know there exists no reductionist approach to eliminating circular dependencies, meaning that there is no recipe consisting of nothing but simple predetermined "no-brainer" steps for taking a system with circular references, applying them one after the other, and ending up with a system free of circular references.  You have to put your mind to work, and you have to perform refactoring steps which are dependent on the nature of your design.

In the particular situation that you have at hand, it seems to me that what you need is a new entity, perhaps called "Game" or "GameLogic", which knows all the other entities, (without any of the other entities knowing it,) so that the other entities do not have to know each other.

For example, it seems to me unreasonable that your RuleBook entity needs to know anything whatsoever about the GameState entity, because a rule book is something that we consult in order to play, it is not something that takes active part in playing.  So, it is this new "Game" entity which needs to consult both the rule book and the game state in order to determine what moves are available, and this eliminates the circular dependencies.

Now, I think I can guess what your problem is going to be with this approach: coding the "Game" entity in a game-agnostic way will be very hard, so you are most likely going to end up with not just one but two entities that will need to have custom-made implementations for each different type of game: the "RuleBook" and the "Game" entity.  Which in turn defeats the purpose of having a "RuleBook" entity in the first place.  Well, all I can say about this is that maybe, just maybe, your initial aspiration of writing a system which can play many different types of games may have been noble, but perhaps ill conceived.  If I were in your shoes I would have focused on using a common mechanism for displaying the state of all the different games, and a common mechanism for receiving user input for all these games, and then I would have allowed the implementation of the different games to vary wildly, having very little code in common, so as to guarantee maximum flexibility in the implementation of each game.

Comment: Thanks Mike.  You're right about the drawbacks of the Game entity; with the old applet code I've been able to draw up new games with little more than a new RuleBook subclass and the appropriate graphic design.

Answer (score 10):

Game theory treats games as a list of previous moves (value types including who played them) and a function ValidMoves(previousMoves)

I would try and follow this pattern for the non UI part of the game and treat things like board setup as moves.

the UI can then be standard OO stuff with one way ref to the logic

---

Update to condense comments

Consider Chess. Games of chess are commonly recorded as lists of moves . http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Game_Notation

the list of moves defines the complete state of the game much better than a picture of the board.

Say for example we start making objects for Board, Piece, Move etc and Methods like Piece.GetValidMoves()

first we see we have to have piece reference the board, but then we consider castling. which you can only do if you have not already moved your king or rook. So we need a MovedAlready flag on the king and rooks. Similarly pawns can move 2 squares on their first move.

Then we see that in castling the valid move of the king depends on the existence and state of the rook, so board needs to have pieces on it and reference those pieces. we are getting into your circular ref problem.

However, if we define Move as an immutable struct and game state as the list of previous moves we find these problems vanish. To see if castling is valid, we can check the move list of the existence of castle and king moves. To see if the pawn can take en-passent we can check to see if the other pawn made a double move on the move before. No references are needed except Rules -> Move

Now chess has a static board, and the peices are always setup the same way. But lets say we have a variant where we allow an alternate setup. perhaps omitting some pieces as a handicap.

If we Add the setup moves as moves, 'from box to square X' and adapet the Rules object to understand that move, then we can still represent the game as a sequence of moves.

Similarly if in your game the board itself is non static, say we can add squares to chess or remove squares from the board so they cant be moved across. These changes can also be represented as Moves without changing the overall structure of your Rules engine or having to reference a **BoardSetup** object of similar

Comment: This will tend to complicate the implementation of ValidMoves, which will slow your logic down.

Comment: not really, I'm assuming the board setup is variable, so you need to define it somehow. If you convert the setup moves to some other struct or object to aid calculation you can cache the result if required. Some games have boards which change with play and some valid moves can depend on previous moves rather than current position (eg. castling in chess)

Comment: Agree that you need to define the board setup.  However going through the history of the game to get the current position will be expensive.  You can have situations where move legality depends on history, and those games would need to look at game history.  But if possible you should try to avoid it, if castling was the only thing I needed history for I would include a flag on the piece to show if it has been moved. -  However in chess you can demand draw by threefold repetition, which means that chess will need to inspect history for some "moves".

Comment: Adding flags and stuff is the complexity you avoid by just having move history. its not expensive to loop over say 100 chess moves to get current board setup and you can cache the result between moves

Comment: What is the cache you keep between moves?  It seems to me that the most straightforward way to do this is the current game state.

Comment: well 'game state' is the list of previous moves. You imply the probable existence of some sort of expensive intermediary calculation between listofmoves and validNextMoves which would be duplicated per turn. All I'm saying that, if that exists, you can cache the result and avoid repeating the expense

Comment: This cache would look a lot like a description of the board.

Comment: maybe for some games, the point is you _can_ generate the board + extra info from the moves. By expressing the game as move history, you ensure avoid complex object hierarchy and referencing problems

Comment: For some games? CAn you give an example where this would not be the case?  Also why is this less prone to circular references than OP's way?

Comment: you also avoid changing your object model to reflect rules. ie for chess, if you make validMoves -> Piece + Board, you fail castling, en-passent, first move for pawns and piece promotion and have to add extra info to the objects or reference a third object. You also lose the idea of who's go it is and concepts such as discovered check

Comment: well obvs games with no boards, like cards or paper scissors stone. but also small boards and no moves like tic tac toe where a move is essentially state. Even in complex games like chess comparing movelists for known plays is going to be just as easy as comparing board snapshots + history flags

Comment: How do you compute what moves are valid in a given state if you don't have an internal representation of the board with the position of each piece? How do you draw the board?

Comment: surely you can see that possible moves are a function of previous moves? google a tictactoe solution

Comment: @Gabe The `boardLayout` is a function of all `priorMoves` (i.e. if we did maintain it as state, nothing would be contributed other than each `thisMove`). Hence Ewan's suggestion is essentially "cut the middle man" - valid moves a direct function of all prior, instead of `validMoves( boardLayout( priorMoves ) )`.

Answer (score 8):

The standard way of removing a circular reference between two classes in object oriented programming is to introduce an interface that can then be implemented by one of them.  So in your case, you could have `RuleBook` referring to `State` which then refers to an `InitialPositionProvider` (which would be an interface implemented by `RuleBook`).  This also makes testing easier, because you can then create a `State` that uses a different (presumably simpler) initial position for test purposes.

Answer (score 7):

I believe the circular references and the god object in your case could be easily removed by separating the control of the game flow from the state and rule models of the game. By doing that you would probably gain a lot of flexibility and get rid of some needless complexity.

I think you should have a controller ("a game master" if you wish) that controls the game flow and handles actual state changes instead of giving the rule book or the game state this responsibility.

A game state object does not need to change itself or to be aware of the rules. The class just needs to provide a model of easily handled (created, inspected, altered, persisted, logged, copied, cached etc) and efficient game state objects for the rest of the application.

The rule book shouldn't need to know about or fiddle with any ongoing game. It should only need a view to a game state to be able to tell which moves are legal and it only needs to answer with a resulting game state when asked what happens when a move is applied to a game state. It could also provide a beginning game state when asked for an initial layout.

The controller has to be aware of game states and the rule book and perhaps some other objects of the game model, but it shouldn't need to mess with the details.

Comment: EXACTLY my thinking. The OP is mixing up too much **data** and **procedure** in the same classes. It's better to split these out more. [This](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/boundaries) is a good talk on the subject. Btw, when I read "view to a game state", I think "argument to the function." +100 if I could.

Answer (score 5):

I think the problem here is that you have not given a clear description of what tasks are to be handled by which classes. I will describe what I think is a good description of what each class should do, then I will give an example of generic code that illustrates the ideas. We will see that the code is less coupled, and so it doesn't really have circular references.

Let's start with describing what each class does.

The `GameState` class should only contain information about the current state of the game. It should not contain any information about what the past states of the game or what future moves are possible. It should only contain information about what pieces are on what squares in chess, or how many and what type of checkers are on what points in backgammon. The `GameState` will have to contain some extra information, like information about castling in chess or about the doubling cube in backgammon.

The `Move` class is a little tricky. I would say that I can specify a move to play by specifying the `GameState` that results from playing the move. So you could imagine that a move can just be implemented as a `GameState`. However, in go (for example) you could imagine that is a lot easier to specify a move by specifying a single point on the board. We want our `Move` class to be flexible enough to handle either of these to cases. Therefore the `Move` class is actually going to be an interface with a method that takes a pre-move `GameState` and returns a new post-move `GameState`.

Now the `RuleBook` class is responsible for knowing everything about the rules. This can be broken down into three things. It needs to know what the initial `GameState` is, it needs to know what moves are legal, and it needs to be able to tell if one of the players has won.

You could also make a `GameHistory` class to keep track of all the moves that have been made and all the `GameStates` that have happened. A new class is necessary because we decided that a single `GameState` should not be responsible for knowing all the `GameState`s that came before it.

This concludes the classes/interfaces I will discuss. You also have a `Board` class. But I think boards in different games are different enough that it is hard to see what could generically be done with boards. Now I will go on to give generic interfaces and implement generic classes.

First is `GameState`. Since this class is completely dependent on the particular game, there is no generic `Gamestate` interface or class.

Next is `Move`. As I said, this can be represented with a interface that has a single method that takes a pre-move state and produces a post-move state. Here is the code for this interface:

```
package boardgame;

/**
 *
 * @param <T> The type of GameState
 */
public interface Move<T> {

    T makeResultingState(T preMoveState) throws IllegalArgumentException;

}
```

Notice that there is a type parameter. This is because, for example, a  `ChessMove` will need to know about the particulars of the pre-move `ChessGameState`. So, for example, the class declaration of `ChessMove` would be

`class ChessMove extends Move<ChessGameState>`,

where you would have already defined a `ChessGameState` class.

Next I will discuss the generic `RuleBook` class. Here is the code:

```
package boardgame;

import java.util.List;

/**
 *
 * @param <T> The type of GameState
 */
public interface RuleBook<T> {

    T makeInitialState();

    List<Move<T>> makeMoveList(T gameState);

    StateEvaluation evaluateState(T gameState);

    boolean isMoveLegal(Move<T> move, T currentState);

}
```

Again there is a type parameter for the `GameState` class. Since the `RuleBook` is supposed to know what the initial state is, we have put a method to give the initial state. Since the `RuleBook` is supposed to know what moves are legal, we have methods to test if a move is legal in a given state and to give a list of legal moves for a given state. Finally, there is a method to evaluate the `GameState`. Notice the `RuleBook` should only be responsible for describing if one or the other players has already won, but not who is in a better position in middle of a game. Deciding who is in a better position is a complicated thing that should be moved into its own class. Therefore the `StateEvaluation` class is actually just a simple enum given as follows:

```
package boardgame;

/**
 *
 */
public enum StateEvaluation {

    UNFINISHED,
    PLAYER_ONE_WINS,
    PLAYER_TWO_WINS,
    DRAW,
    ILLEGAL_STATE
}
```

Lastly, let's describe the `GameHistory` class. This class is responsible for remembering all positions that were reached in the game as well as the moves that were played. The main thing it should be able to do is record a `Move` as played. You can also add functionality for undoing `Move`s. I have an implementation below.

```
package boardgame;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 *
 * @param <T> The type of GameState
 */
public class GameHistory<T> {

    private List<T> states;
    private List<Move<T>> moves;

    public GameHistory(T initialState) {
        states = new ArrayList<>();
        states.add(initialState);
        moves = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    void recordMove(Move<T> move) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        moves.add(move);
        states.add(move.makeResultingState(getMostRecentState()));
    }

    void resetToNthState(int n) {
        states = states.subList(0, n + 1);
        moves = moves.subList(0, n);
    }

    void undoLastMove() {
        resetToNthState(getNumberOfMoves() - 1);
    }

    T getMostRecentState() {
        return states.get(getNumberOfMoves());
    }

    T getStateAfterNthMove(int n) {
        return states.get(n + 1);
    }

    Move<T> getNthMove(int n) {
        return moves.get(n);
    }

    int getNumberOfMoves() {
        return moves.size();
    }

}
```

Finally, we could imagine making a `Game` class to tie everything together. This `Game` class is supposed to expose methods that make it possible for people to see what the current `GameState` is, see who, if anyone has one, see what moves can be played, and play a move. I have an implementation below

```
package boardgame;

import java.util.List;

/**
 *
 * @author brian
 * @param <T> The type of GameState
 */
public class Game<T> {

    GameHistory<T> gameHistory;
    RuleBook<T> ruleBook;

    public Game(RuleBook<T> ruleBook) {
        this.ruleBook = ruleBook;
        final T initialState = ruleBook.makeInitialState();
        gameHistory = new GameHistory<>(initialState);
    }

    T getCurrentState() {
        return gameHistory.getMostRecentState();
    }

    List<Move<T>> getLegalMoves() {
        return ruleBook.makeMoveList(getCurrentState());
    }

    void doMove(Move<T> move) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        if (!ruleBook.isMoveLegal(move, getCurrentState())) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Move is not legal in this position");
        }
        gameHistory.recordMove(move);
    }

    void undoMove() {
        gameHistory.undoLastMove();
    }

    StateEvaluation evaluateState() {
        return ruleBook.evaluateState(getCurrentState());
    }

}
```

Notice in this class that the `RuleBook` is not responsible for knowing what the current `GameState` is. That is the `GameHistory`'s job. So the `Game` asks the `GameHistory` what the current state is and gives this information to the `RuleBook` when the `Game` needs to say what the legal moves are or if anyone has won.

Anyway, the point of this answer is that once you have made a reasonable determination of what each class is responsible for, and you make each class focused on a small number of responsibilities, and you assign each responsibility to a unique class, then the classes tend to be decoupled, and everything gets easy to code. Hopefully that is apparent from the code examples I gave.

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, circular references generally indicate that your design isn't well-thought-out.

In your design, I don't understand why RuleBook needs to "know" about the State. It might receive a State as a *parameter* to some method, sure, but why should it need to *know* (i.e. hold as an instance variable) a reference to a State? That doesn't make sense to me. A RuleBook doesn't need to "know" about the state of any particular game in order to do its job; the rules of the game don't change depending on the current state of the game. So either you've designed it incorrectly, or you've designed it correctly but are explaining it incorrectly.

Comment: +1. You buy a physical board game, you get a rule book that is able to describe the rules without state.

Answer (score 1):

The circular dependency isn't necessarily a technical problem, but it should be considered a code smell, that usually is a violation of the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Your circular dependency comes from the fact that you're trying to do too much from your `State` object.

Any stateful object should only provide methods that directly relate to managing that local state. If it requires anything more than the most basic logic, then it should probably be broken out into a larger pattern. Some people have different opinions about this, but as a general rule of thumb, if you're doing anything more than getters and setters on data, you're doing too much.

In this case, you'd be better off having a `StateFactory`, which could know about a `Rulebook`. You'd probably have another controller class which uses your `StateFactory` to create a new game. `State` definitely shouldn't know about `Rulebook`. `Rulebook` might know about a `State` depending on the implementation of your rules.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any need for a rulebook object to be bound to a particular game state, or would it make more sense to have a rulebook object with a method that, given a game state, will report what moves are available from that state (and, having reported that, remember nothing about the state in question)?  Unless there is something to be gained by having the object which is asked about available moves retain a memory of the game state, there's no need for it to persist a reference.

It's possible in some cases there would be advantages to having the rules-evaluating object maintain state.  If you think such a situation may arise, I would suggest adding a "referee" class, and having the rulebook provide a "createReferee" method.  Unlike the rulebook, which cares nothing whether it's asked about one game, or fifty, a referee object would expect to officiate one game.  It wouldn't be expected to encapsulate all of the state related to the game it's officiating, but could cache whatever information about the game it deemed useful.  If a game supports "undo" functionality, it may be helpful to have the referee include a means of producing a "snapshot" object which could be stored along with earlier game states; that object should, given a copy of the game state when it was created, be able to in turn produce a new referee which whose state should match the state the original referee had when the snapshot was created.

If some coupling might be necessary between the rules-processing and game-state-processing aspects of the code, using a referee object will make it possible to keep such coupling *out* of the main rulesbook and game-state classes.  It may also make it possible to have new rules consider aspects of game state that the game-state class wouldn't consider relevant (e.g. if a rule was added which said "Object X can't do Y if it's ever been to location Z", the referee could be changed to keep track of which objects have been to location Z without having to change the game-state class).

Answer (score -2):

The proper way of dealing with this is to use interfaces. Instead of having two classes know about eachother, have each class implement an interface and reference that in the other class. 
Let's say you have class A and class B that need to reference eachother. Have class A implement interface A and class B implement interface B then you can reference interface B from class A and interface A from class B.
Class A can than be in it's own project, as can class B. The interfaces are in a seperate project which both other projects reference.

Comment: this seems to merely repeat points made and explained in a [prior answer](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/285268/31260) posted few hours before this one